# var name produces strange result in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

Lets say we have this code segment :

```
var name = ["Apples","Oranges","Strawberries"];
console.log(name.length);
```

This code produces this weird result of 27 !! The issue seems to be with using the variable name as 'name' which seems like a reserved keyword.

But can anyone explain why this weird behavior ?

Comment: I can't reproduce it: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/w3QX2/

Comment: I can reproduce it on Chrome console : the array is cast to a string (hence the length). Obviously this changes the window.name property, and as it must be a string, it casts it.

Comment: Ahh, it depends on whether the code is inside a function. I reproduced it here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/w3QX2/1/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It refers to `window.name`, which is the name of the window.

You can use the window's name to target hyperlinks, but it's not typically useful.

More info on `window.name`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.name

Just testing in chrome:
You can't stop `var name` from being `window.name`, which is a string. No matter what you set the value to, it will be cast as a string so that it is a valid window name. So, `name.length` is the amount of characters in the string. It's best to avoid variable or be very careful about them!

As I can see from some of the other comments, this is an odd concept if you're new to it. The concern is over what `window.name` refers to. `window.name` *is* the name of the window. Any use of it is naming the window.

**Defending that Chrome's behavior is logical:**

If this `var document = 'foo'` did what it looks like it would do, you would have overwritten `window.document` - the document object - with a string. That would be quite the problem. `name` is a property of `window` just like `document` and has a use that shouldn't be (and can't be in Chrome) replaced.

Comment: I believe any global variable can be referenced as `window.variable_name`, so in this case I guess it's predefined.

Comment: @yitwail it's not a matter of that...`name` is special - it must be a string because of what it is used for.

Comment: @m59: The real issue is that global variables are "fields" of the window object. Even if it didn't get cast to a string, it would still be wrong - the name of the window would be overwritten by the array!

Comment: @Luaan right, I'm trying to explain that in a way everyone would understand hehe. It's a bit abstract if you aren't used to it.

Comment: Yes, this indeed seems to be the problem because window.name shows up the same values when we set var name manually. And yes Firefox for instance doesn't seem to have this issue so it has to be a Chrome quirk.

Comment: What FF does is too magical in my opinion. Chrome's behavior is consistent with the DOM+JS world.

Comment: @ShadowFax Chrome's behavior is the better one! Overwriting the window's name is comparable (but not as disastrous) as overwriting the document itself.

Comment: @dystroy: True, but it has its logic too. FF goes with the JS way of "variables can have their type changed", while Chrome goes with "window.name has a given type".

Comment: @Luaan We're not really talking of variables but of accessors, here.

Comment: @dystroy: Which is basically a leaky abstraction manifesting - global variables are not really variables. As you say, when you (unknowingly) select a variable name, that is already in the window object, you get no warning, error or whatever - you just pretty much get undefined behaviour. This is as much a problem of DOM as it is of JS itself (ECMAScript defines a "global environment" in which global variables are stored, and in DHTML, the `window` object is this global environment, for better and worse). All I'm saying is that it would be helpful to get a warning when magic happens :)

Answer (score 6):

In the global scope, when you do `var name = ["Apples","Oranges","Strawberries"];`, it's the same as `window.name = ["Apples","Oranges","Strawberries"];`.

`window.name` must be a string, so it assign `["Apples","Oranges","Strawberries"].toString()` to it which is `"Apples,Oranges,Strawberries"`.

Answer (score 2):

[What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope) is a good start. Basically, when you're declaring `name` outside of a function, you're actually hiding the `window.name` value, which is a very, very bad idea (be very careful about any global variables you declare - they are actually values of the `window` object - including hiding existing values.

As others have said, the fact that Google Chrome forces the type to string is probably a Chrome quirk (although somewhat understandable), but the underlying cause is that you're simply doing something "dangerous" you didn't realize you're doing :)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others, in the when you are using the variable named `name` in the global scope it is treated as `window.name`.

From experimentation under Google Chrome, `window.name` gets the value as a string, like so: `"Apples,Oranges,Strawberries"`, This behaviour is because Google Chrome is forcing `window.name` to be string. This explains why `name.length` will report `27` as that is the length of the string given.

This behaviour is not present in IE, Opera or Firefox which assing the array `["Apples","Oranges","Strawberries"]` and report `3` on `` `name.length `` as expected, therefore I guess this is a quirk of Google Chrome.

Comment: To me Chrome's behavior looks like the only logical behavior.

Comment: @dystroy True, but it only seems logical if you actually understand that global variables aren't variables at all, but rather, they assign to a "field" in the `window` object. This is a significant readability issue in (browser) JavaScript and it would be nice if the browser produced a warning ("you're declaring a variable that hides an existing field in `window`" or something like that). If you want to change `window.name`, just assign to `window.name`. Having `var name` do the same is very confusing.

Comment: @dystroy I did refer to it as a quirk instead of bug because I think it makes sense. Although I have tested on Firefox, IE and Opera and they are not doing this. They assign the array and report `3` on `name.length` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

the window object has a property "name";

if you define 'name' in a closure function you may get 3

you defined var name in the global object, so you just initialized a string obj;

```
(function(){
  var name = ["Apples","Oranges","Strawberries"];
  consol.log(name.length);
})()

var name = ["Apples","Oranges","Strawberries"];
```

the global window.name is a build in string object(reserved), so name.toString() is called when you excuete the line above;

Comment: above code give a syntax error, it should be console instead of  consol