# weird output by instanceof in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, instanceof

when I am doing the following snippet

```
var name = new String("NewDelhi");
var count = new Number(10);
console.log(name instanceof String); //false
console.log(count instanceof Number); //true
```

when I am using **name** as variable it showing me false 
while giving it some other variable it showing true

```
var str = new String("NewDelhi");
var count = new Number(10);
console.log(str instanceof String); //true
console.log(count instanceof Number); //true
```

why is this happening.

Comment: This would be the issue in hiding window variables (`window.name`, which is a primitive, so `window.name instanceof String === false`) with silly variable names

Comment: ^ that, you're accessing `window.name`, which can't be an object

Answer (score 1):

That's because `name` is not a variable, it's a property in the `window` object. When you try to create a global variable named `name`, that will be ignored and the existing property will be used instead.

The type of the property is a string primitive, not a string object. The type of a variable is dynamic, so it could both hold a string primitive or a String object, but the property has a specific type and can only hold a string primitive.

`typeof name` will return `"string"`, not `"object"`. As it's not an object, it's not an instance of the `String` class.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote and runned a little snippet

```
function test(){
    window.name = 'Hello World';
    alert(name);
}
```

If you try it you will see it will output "Hello World", so your problem is caused by the **scope of the variable**.

When you are calling `console.log(name instanceof String)`, you are actually doing `console.log(window.name instanceof String);`

Moreover window.name is a **primitive string** and not an object, so to check if it is a string try something like this:

```
alert(typeof name === "string" );
```

And it will output `'true'`!

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers don't seem to emphasize that this is a **special case**. This behaviour is not only because the global `window` object already has a name param, but because window.name (=equivalent to the global `name` in a browser environment) is treated as a special case, ie. always casted into a primitive string.

Other properties defined on the global window object don't have this behaviour, you can try adding a property yourself:

```
window.xyz = "primitive";
window.xyz = new String("NewDelhi");
window.xyz;
> String {0: "N", 1: "e", 2: "w", 3: "D", 4: "e", 5: "l", 6: "h", 7: "i", length: 8, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "NewDelhi"}
```

The reason it's treated as such is so that the original semantics of the property can be kept: it is the name of the window, anything but a primitive string wouldn't make sense.

See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945498/var-name-produces-strange-result-in-javascript) for more details *(which might even warrant marking this question as a duplicate)*.

Comment: It's not really a special case. There are lots of properties which exhibit this behaviour

Comment: @RGraham my issue was mostly that if someone isn't familiar with the language, from the other answers might have concluded that a property's type is somehow always static - which is not the general case.

Comment: I see what you mean - that there are properties on `window` which are special cases, rather than `window.name` specifically

Answer (score 0):

**"name" is kind of a reserved property of the Window object.**

***Even though you initialize it as global variable it is ignored by default as it is already the property of Window object.***

var name = new String("NewDelhi");

Now name is the property of the Window object and not the instance of String class.

The property can only hold string primitive.

Thank you.