# If a var in JavaScript is defined twice, which definition should the interpreter take?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, var, hoisting

I'm new to JavaScript and am trying to understand the concepts of hoisting and scope.

**Case 1**

```js
var name;

function logName(num) {
  console.log(name, num);
}

logName(1);
name = "Auro";
logName(2);
```

and I have the following output in the console

```
Auro 1
Auro 2
```

If I understand `hoisting` correctly, JS engine hoists the declaration of a variable first and then automatically assigns a value `undefined` to it. Only when it encounters the assignment (`=`) operator, does it actually assign the intended value to it.

If my understanding above is correct, then the first time the `logName` function was called, the variable `name` should have printed undefined, but it is printing the value.

**Case 2**

```js
var name;

function logName(num) {
  console.log(name, num);
}

logName(1);
name = "Auro";
logName(2);
name = "Baner";
```

Output in the console:

```
Baner 1
Auro 2
```

This confuses me even more. Here the first call to the function `logName` picked the later assignment to the variable and printed `Baner`, however, the second call picked the previous assignment, that is `Auro`.

What is going on here? What am I missing?

Comment: first log don't output `Auro 1`

Comment: In *neither* of those examples do I get what you claim to get.

Comment: Are you testing these in the console multiple times? If you are, I'd guess that `name` is still around from the last time you ran it

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945498/var-name-produces-strange-result-in-javascript.

Comment: Problem here is a bad variable name! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name

Comment: Issue could also be addressed with an IIFE to reduce the scope.

Comment: @CodeManiac True. First log doesn't output, only re-run gives that. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @loganfsmyth Yep, that's what I was doing without realizing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the global scope, `name` refers to `window.name`, that is the `name` property of the window - which in the examples you gave are `sif1` and `sif2` (possibly "Snippet IFrame 1/2").

Since `window.name` already exists, `var name;` in the global scope does nothing. The variable is already defined.

Until you overwrite it - and note that again you are setting the global `window.name` property. And, depending on browser settings, this can persist across reloads of the page (since you're naming the entire `window`). This explains why you see the value "stick".

Comment: Nice call out on the iframe names.  When I updated the question to make them snippets, that threw me for a loop, ^_^

Comment: If you press blue 'Run...' button twice then browser will open new tab in your compuer too - or it works like that only in my local browser?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski That would be because, having renamed `window.name`, the "Run" button can no longer find a frame with the desired name and so a new window/tab is opened - with that name.

Answer (score 0):

As addition to other answers I can say, that just not use `var` but use ES6  `let` or `const` instead and 'surprising behaviour' will disappear.

```js
let name;

function logName(num) {
  console.log(name, num);
}

logName(1);
name = "Auro";
logName(2);
name = "Baner";
```

Answer (score 0):

No none of the specified output matches, as initially you have value of `name` equal to [**window.name**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name), so initially the value of `name` variable will be equal to `winow.name` and once overwrite it you get the new value

let's understand how this all works

You can understand as such there are two phase of code execution

1. Creation phase
2. Execution phase

***Creation phase:-*** During creation phase function is hoisted at top as it is, while the variable are hoisted but there is no value assigned to it ( or you can say it's value is undefined )

***Execution phase:-*** During execution context it assigns value to variable when it reaches line where assignment is happening

```js
var name;

function logName(num) {
  console.log(name, num);
}

logName(1);
name = "Auro";
logName(2);
name = "Baner";
```