# Input value undefined when using var in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

Here is my code

```js
var form = document.querySelector('form');
var name = form.querySelector('div #name');

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(name.value); // undefined
})
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <input id="name" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

console.log prints `undefined` if I use var when declaring `name`. But prints the actual value if I use `const` instead of `var`.

```
const name = form.querySelector('div #name');
```

I guess it's a hoisting problem, but can't understand why it's happening. Anyone please explain why it's not working while using `var`.

Comment: Plz read more here, https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: @AsiqurRahman it's not a scope issue. Also, w3schools isn't a good source of information as it contains many errors

Comment: Try giving the input the `name` attribute. Then the controls should populate the forms value

Comment: @AsiqurRahman I read it but it doesn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

That's indeed weird at first, but after reading other questions:

- [Using the variable "name" doesn't work with a JS object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523701/using-the-variable-name-doesnt-work-with-a-js-object)
- [var name produces strange result in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945498/var-name-produces-strange-result-in-javascript)

I found a solution

For compatibility reasons using `var` in a global scope assigns a variable as a property of the global `window` object. So `var name = ...` is equal to `window.name = ...`

[`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) is a special property that can only be a string, so `var name = form.querySelector('div #name');` converts HTML element to string. You can check this by running `typeof name`.

Hence you can't access the properties of the HTML element.

Another reason to always use `const` or `let`

Comment: got it now. It has been long time since I'm not working with vanilla js, so I forgot about the `window` object .

Answer (score 1):

Using `var` assigns the variable to the `window` object, and is therefore equivalent to:

```
 window.name = form.querySelector('div #name');
```

and the result is cast to a string, and strings don't have any properties, hence `undefined`.

`const` doesn't assign to `window`([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#description)), and so `name` is assigned as the element.

Comment: Understand now.